# JAVA with POI XWPF

Tags: apache-poi, xwpf

how can I set paragraph property "Keep with next" in POI XWPF?
I tried to look for an example, but I did not find.
I would like to have a Title paragraph together with your "body" paragraph.
In Word, you can specify a property in Paragraph Dialog called "Keep with next".
How can I do it in POI XWPF?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a paragraph to a style that includes `Keep with next`. For example the `Heading#` styles default to `Keep with next`.

Otherwise you will have to use the CT classes like this

```
CTP ctP = xwpfParagraph.getCTP();
CTPPr ctPPr = ctP.isSetPPr() ? ctP.getPPr() : ctP.addNewPPr();
CTOnOff keepNext = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
keepNext.setVal(STOnOff.ON);
ctPPr.setKeepNext(keepNext);
```